# Google maps standard infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I used Google maps with a custom infowindow
http://jsfiddle.net/hashie5/KYtnb/
It pops up when u click the marker
How can I use the standard infowindow, as used in google maps itself
example: http://maps.google.be/maps?q=Jaarbeurslaan,+Genk&hl=nl&ll=50.965036,5.485032&spn=0.01046,0.033023&sll=51.09623,4.227975&sspn=1.335072,4.22699&oq=jaar&hnear=Jaarbeurslaan,+3600+Genk,+Limburg,+Vlaams+Gewest&t=m&z=16&iwloc=A

So I can use the 'Routebeschrijving' (Directions) link etc.

```
function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.965049,5.484231);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 14,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var contentString =
    '<div id="infowindow">' +
    'Galaconcert<br />' +
    'Jaarbeurslaan 2-6<br />' +
    '3690 Genk' +
    '</div>'
;

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Galaconcert'
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
}
$(function(){
    initialize();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the "infowindow from Google Maps" (unless you use an embedded Google Map).  But you can implement the same functionality yourself using the API [Directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) or by creating a link to Google Maps.